# Upload image to member area, subject to admin approval

Tags: php, image-processing, image-uploading

I'm trying to create a members site using php where they can upload images (dynamically create thumbnails) and comments for all members to see. I want all uploads to be published only after admin approval.

I can do quite a lot of this (registration, login, and even basic upload)but would be grateful if someone can provide a link to any lessons or videos of how to put it all together. I really would like to learn how to do it rather than configure someone's script.

I've checked YouTube but cannot find exactly what I'm looking for.

Thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow is not your personal research assistant. What have you tried so far, where have you looked?

Comment: There's always some hater with nothing but negativity. i have watched dozens of php videos on youtube, searched google, reviewed scripts and so on. I am trying to learn by doing, not just using someone else's script and I thought the idea was to help each other by pointing someone in the right direction, which is what most helpful  people do. Go back to eating sour fruit and let those who want to learn continue to do so.

Comment: I think it is more about the content of your question. It is not really asking to help solve a specific issue (See http://stackoverflow.com/faq). It is a rather broad and general question. In addition, categorising members as haters who request some of the code you may have already written to see how this can become a more specific question they can help you with is rather counter-productive. In addition to youtube and web tutorials, there is also the choice of good old fashioned books. Amazon for example has a great collection of PhP books for all skill levels.

Answer (score 2):

In order to do an approval system, I think the most simple way to do it is to have a field in a DB, for each comment, image, etc, named "approved", which can take a 0,1 or 2 as value.s

If it's 0, it means it needs approval. 1 means it's approved. 2 means it is disapproved.

Note that 2 is not really necessary. It's just to distinguish new entries from old entries that weren't approved.

Then, on the backend, you can only give access to the approval system to the admin. You can use the same approach to define admins, users, moderators, etc...

Comment: Thanks Joao, I understand what you're saying. I have watched many good youtube videos and tutorials around the web but can't seem to put it all together.

Comment: @Jack Glad to help. But as it was said, this is not a "there you go" comunity. The best way for you to understand the concept I gave you is to get your hands dirty on it and start doing.

Comment: Mate my hands are filthy, I didn't see the point of pasting several hundred lines of code and ask help in finishing it, I'm happy to do it myself which is why I asked if someone had found a site with tutorials that I have not.